# Retrieve data from three table using join in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to get result from three table using CodeIgnitor active record. But I am just getting record who match with second join condition only. But I need all record..

```
$uid   = $this->session->userdata('uid');
$codn  = ['stud.uid'=>$uid,'stud.status'=>"ACTIVE"];

$liststudent = $this->db->select('stud.id,stud.studname,stud.mobile1,stud.photo,stud.totalfees,bs.title,SUM(sp.pay_in_digit) AS paidfees')
                        ->from('students as stud')
                        ->join('batchsetting as bs', 'bs.id  = stud.bid')
                        ->join('stud_payment as sp', 'sp.sid = stud.id')
                        ->where($codn)
                        ->get();
return $liststudent->result();
```

Here is the my query.

Concept is: I need batch title from batchsetting who's 'id = stud.bid'. and sum of paidfees from stud_payment who's 'sid=stud.id'.

But in result I am getting only those record of student who's record avail in stud_payment table.

Comment: You need to add join type like join('batchsetting as bs', 'bs.id  = stud.bid','FULL')

Comment: @MandipVora nop still have the same result :(

Answer (score 0):

Table `students` has not any field named as `bid`.So

**Change**

```
 ->join('batchsetting as bs', 'bs.id  = stud.bid')
```

**to**

```
 ->join('batchsetting as bs', 'bs.id  = stud.id')
```

Comment: nop it will not work. Concept is: I need batch title from batchsetting whos id is stud.bid. and sum of paidfees from stud_payment whos sid=stud.id. But is result I am getting only those record of student who's record avail in stud_payment table

Comment: see your query using `$this->db->last_query();` and try in `phpmyadmin` or `mysql` console.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code

```
$uid   = $this->session->userdata('uid');
$liststudent = $this->db->select('stud.id,stud.studname,stud.mobile1,stud.photo,stud.totalfees,bs.title,SUM(sp.pay_in_digit) AS paidfees')
                    ->from('students as stud')
                    ->join('batchsetting as bs', 'bs.id  = stud.id')
                    ->join('stud_payment as sp', 'sp.sid = stud.id')
                    ->where('stud.uid',$uid)
                    ->where('stud.status',"ACTIVE");
return $liststudent->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a left join in your jointure. Code below :

```
$uid   = $this->session->userdata('uid');
$codn  = ['stud.uid'=>$uid,'stud.status'=>"ACTIVE"];

$liststudent = $this->db->select('stud.id,stud.studname,stud.mobile1,stud.photo,stud.totalfees,bs.title,SUM(sp.pay_in_digit) AS paidfees')
                        ->from('students as stud')
                        ->join('batchsetting as bs', 'bs.id  = stud.bid', 'left')
                        ->join('stud_payment as sp', 'sp.sid = stud.id', 'left')
                        ->where($codn)
                        ->get();
return $liststudent->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically ci bydefault consider inner Join query.so you need to specify left join

```
->join('stud_payment as sp', 'sp.sid = stud.id', 'left');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use full outer join.

```
function full_outer_join() {
    $sql = 'SELECT ' . $this->blogs . '.blog_id,comment_id,blog_title,blog_content,blog_date,comment_text,comment_date
            FROM ' . $this->blogs . ' LEFT OUTER JOIN ' . $this->blog_comments . ' ON ' . $this->blog_comments . '.blog_id = ' . $this->blogs . '.blog_id
                UNION
            SELECT ' . $this->blogs . '.blog_id,comment_id,blog_title,blog_content,blog_date,comment_text,comment_date
            FROM ' . $this->blogs . ' RIGHT OUTER JOIN ' . $this->blog_comments . ' ON ' . $this->blog_comments . '.blog_id = ' . $this->blogs . '.blog_id';
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result();
}
```